# awk: search for pattern stored in an array

Tags: awk

I use `awk` to parse a file. Have stored pattern words in an `awk` array. Would like to do something like this.

```
if ( $0 ~ / arr[1] / ){
blah
}
```

I want to check if the pattern stored in the array element is found in the current line which is being parsed.

Comment: I want to check if the pattern stored in the array element is found in the current line.

Answer (score 1):

Just use the array accessing afterwards, no need for the `//` as then the `arr[1]` will be taken as a Regex pattern, do:

```
if ( $0 ~ arr[1] ){ blah }
```

**Example:**

```
% awk 'BEGIN{a[1]="foo"} {if ($0 ~ /a[1]/) print "Matched"}' <<<'foobar'  
% awk 'BEGIN{a[1]="foo"} {if ($0 ~ a[1]) print "Matched"}' <<<'foobar' 
Matched
```

Comment: @andromeda64 No problem. Don't forget to mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: I did, but since I am new, it has recorded the feedback but would not show to public.